# HttpStatusCodeResult in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have noticed that ASP.NET MVC 3 introduces a HttpStatusCodeResult action result. How do we do the equivalent in ASP.NET MVC 2? I want to return a 410 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something here that does just what I want
http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/28/asp-net-mvc-3-creating-httpstatuscoderesult-with-view-based-body.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own HttpStatusCodeResult which might look something like this:

```
public class HttpStatusCodeResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly int code;
    public HttpStatusCodeResult(int code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = code;
    }
}
```